# Use Redshift as Pentaho PDI database repository

Tags: pentaho, amazon-redshift, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I am running Spoon here on PDI CE 7.0 and trying to set up for the first time my database repository.
I am able to use a SQL Server as my database repository, but I was wondering if I could use my Redshift server as my database repository.

When I test my database connection, it runs fine.
However, when I try to connect to the repository I receive an error message saying that "You don't seem to be getting a connection to the server. Please check the path you're using and make sure the server is up and running" ([Click to see error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ5z6.png))

I already tried changing my JDBC driver. I have tested with the Postgresql Driver 9.3 and 8.4 and also with Amazon's Redshift Driver. With all these options I got the same message.

Is it possible to use Redshift as my database repository?

This is the stack trace I receive from Spoon Console.

```
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : Unable to connect to repository
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : 

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
 Error connecting to the repository!
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -

2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -

No repository exists on the specified connection.

To create a repository, select the Edit' button followed by the 'Create or upgra
de' button.
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -

2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -

2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConne
ctionDelegate.connect(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:165)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.connect(Kettle
DatabaseRepository.java:193)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.connect(Kettle
DatabaseRepository.java:182)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController.connectToRepositor
y(RepositoryConnectController.java:217)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController.connectToRepositor
y(RepositoryConnectController.java:201)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryDialog$12.function(RepositoryDialog.
java:179)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebSite.Invoke(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebSite$7.method6(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(Unknown Source
)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryDialog.open(RepositoryDialog.java:25
4)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryDialog.open(RepositoryDialog.java:85
)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryDialog.open(RepositoryDialog.java:81
)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryDialog.openManager(RepositoryDialog.
java:263)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectMenu$3$2.widgetSelected(Repos
itoryConnectMenu.java:176)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
 Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -

No repository exists on the specified connection.

To create a repository, select the Edit' button followed by the 'Create or upgra
de' button.
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -

2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConne
ctionDelegate.verifyVersion(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:213)

2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConne
ctionDelegate.connect(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:151)
2017/07/04 13:48:00 - class org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectController -
        ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Redshift as a repository. Redshift is a large scale datawarehouse, with column oriented storage, whereas the repository is an operational database which works best in row oriented storage.

Having said that, you should look into the actual log message (in Spoon they'll be in the console) to identify the cause. As a first guess I would check whether you have the JDBC driver installed.

Comment: Thanks nsousa. I know it is not optimal to use Redshift as the repository, but since I already have it setup to run as my datawarehouse I tought it would be easier to use it as a repository as well. Also, my Driver seems to be working because I am able to test the connection I am setting the connection up and it works fine. I am able to see the schemas and tables I have there. it looks like it is having troubles to create the repository tables on my first access.

Comment: I am getting "You don't seem to be getting a connection to the server. Please check the path you're using and make sure the server is up and running"

Comment: Check the logs. That type of error usually produces a fairly large and descriptive exception and stack trace. Could be A) incorrect host; b) incorrect db name or port; c) unknown user d): incorrect username/password combo; e) other. And without the actual logs it's impossible to determine which.